# $A$ is convex $\iff$ for all $s,t \gt 0$ , $(s+t)A = sA + tA$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a TVS ,and $A \subset X$.

Then $A$ is convex $\iff$ for all $s,t \gt 0$ , $(s+t)A = sA + tA$.

If for all $s,t\gt 0$ we have $(s+t)A = sA+tA$ then of course $A$ is convex.

I'm not sure about the other direction. It is always true that $(s+t)A \subset sA+tA$ ,so assuming $A$ is convex I need to show the other inclusion.

Any ideas?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $sx+ty\in sA+tA$. Then $$(s+t)\left(\frac{s}{s+t}x+\frac{t}{s+t}y\right)\in(s+t)A$$

Comment: So easy. Thanks!